# Get a cookie by name, and replace some symbols

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have some code on website, im read cookie, and then send this cookie and another data to crm ( sendpulse )
My code so bad i know, but this working(
This code read _gid value cookie

```js
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)_gid\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

function alertCookieValue() {
return(cookieValue);
}
```

I need to remove . and GA letters from value cookie.
Now i have resul like this *GA1.2.973313479.1623553809*
I need 973313479.1623553809

Comment: `.replace(/^GA\d\.\d\./, '')` or `.split('.').slice(-2).join('.')`

Comment: can you type all script ?
my target value call _gid?

Comment: no need, you just apply one of those snippets to the result you have